# SQL server Retrieve week start date and week end date from week number and year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve the start and the end date of a year's week.

This is my input:

```
YEAR = 2019 WEEK = 32
```

The result will be: `05/08/2019` and `11/08/2019`.

I tried this:

```
select (dateadd(week,32-(1),dateadd(week,datediff(week,(-1),dateadd(year,datediff(year,(0),getdate()),(0))),(0))))
select (dateadd(week,32+datediff(week,(0),dateadd(year,datediff(year,(0),getdate()),(0))),(-1)))
```

but there is no year input, so it will work only for the current year
I need to put this function, into a calculated fields, creating table

Comment: There are differing definitions for week numbering. Do you know which one you've got?

Comment: You might also consider creating a calendar table so you just do this as lookup.

Comment: I don't want to create a calendar table, I don't need it

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is the following statement:

```
DECLARE @year int = 2019
DECLARE @week int = 32
DECLARE @date date

SELECT @date = DATEADD(week, (@week - 1), DATEFROMPARTS(@year, 1, 1))
SELECT
   @date AS CurrentDay,
   DATEADD(day, - DATEPART(weekday, @date) + 1, @date) AS StartOfTheWeek,
   DATEADD(day, 7 - DATEPART(weekday, @date), @date) AS EndOfTheWeek
```

Result:

```
CurrentDay  StartOfTheWeek  EndOfTheWeek
2019-08-06  2019-08-05      2019-08-11
```

If you want to define a table with calculated columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
    [Year] int,
    [Week] int,
    [Start_Date] AS DATEADD (
        day, 
        - DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(week, ([Week] - 1), DATEFROMPARTS([Year], 1, 1))) + 1, 
        DATEADD(week, ([Week] - 1), DATEFROMPARTS([Year], 1, 1))
    ),
    [End_Date] AS DATEADD (
        day, 
        7 - DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(week, ([Week] - 1), DATEFROMPARTS([Year], 1, 1))),
        DATEADD(week, ([Week] - 1), DATEFROMPARTS([Year], 1, 1))
    )
)

INSERT INTO Data ([Year], [Week])
VALUES (2019, 32)
```

Comment: Thanks but I need it to a inline function as a calculated field

Comment: @img.simone What is the table definition and what is the expected output from the function execution? Thanks.

Comment: The table definition is: YEAR, WEEK, START_DATE, END_DATE. The last two fields must be calculated. The output is the same one you proposed

Comment: i need to use this function in a calculated field. Your solution could be great,  but no useful for me

Comment: @img.simone What do you want - to define a fucntion and use this function in a calculated field? Or something else? If possible, update the question with additional explanations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with `STR_TO_DATE`: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/Toconvertayearweektoadatethenyoushouldalsospecifytheweekday.htm

Comment: Thanks but It's not mysql